# Let R be a commutative ring with unity, Prove {0} is a prime ideal in R if and only if R is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

So by definition of an integral domain I need to only show that R has no zero divisors based on the fact I have a prime ideal {0}. Not seeing a connection there, any tips?

Answer (score 3):

What it means for an ideal $I$ to be prime is
$$ab \in I \quad \Rightarrow \quad a \in I\ \text{or}\ b \in I$$
Letting $I=\{0\}$, this is precisely the definition of $R$ being an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since $R/I$ is an integral domain $\iff$ $I$ is prime, we have $R/\{0\}=R$ is an integral domain $\iff$ $\{0\}$ is prime.

---

To elaborate, suppose $\{0\}$ is a prime ideal. Then for $x,y\in R/\{0\}$ we have $xy\in \{0\}$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$ and thus $R$ is an integral domain. Conversely, if $R$ is an integral domain, then there are no zero divisors. So if $xy=0$ we have $x=0$ or $y=0$ meaning $\{0\}$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: How are you coming up wit R/I if that was not given I'm not seing where that came from

Comment: @Nicole Look up prime ideal $\iff$ quotient is an integral domain.

Comment: oh got it that was easy thanks!

Comment: @Nicole Yay! :)